# Prevent full screen application from taking over system shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-desktop

I'm currently facing the problem that a fullscreen app (Windows inside AWS Workspaces in my case) is taking over system shortcuts (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) from the host operating system (Windows). Is there a way to stop the guest OS/fullscreen app from doing this such that <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> always triggers the host operating system?

Comment: This is an issue with any VM or remote desktop process, whether fullscreen or not. My usual solution is to make sure my own computer uses non-standard key commands for the most irritating clashes, which avoids me having to change defaults on every other computer I ever have to access. VMs sometimes have preference overrides to avoid this, but idk quite how AWS works in this respect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Sounds like a viable solution to navigate around this issue.

Comment: I can drop that into the answer space. Wait a while before accepting, just in case someone knows of a specific 'fix' for AWS.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot for the help. Out of curiosity, do you have any suggestions about shortcuts that don't clash?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Mac, so my shortcuts & methods of changing them will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with any VM or remote desktop process, whether fullscreen or not.

My usual solution is to make sure my own computer uses non-standard key commands for the most irritating clashes, which avoids me having to change defaults on every other computer I ever have to access.

VMs sometimes have preference overrides to avoid this, but idk quite how AWS works in this respect.